# OpenWeatherMap API not loading at start of app

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api, openweathermap

I'm trying to make a weather app in RN. This is my code so far:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import axios from "axios";
import * as Location from "expo-location"
import WeatherScreen from './Screens/WeatherScreen';


export default function App() {
const [weatherData,setWeatherData] = useState()
const [city,setCity]= useState()
const [dataLoaded,setDataLoaded]= useState()

const fetchWeatherDara = async() =>{
  try{

    setDataLoaded(false)
    const response = await  fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=44.34&lon=10.99&appid=key")
    if(response.status == 200){
      const data = await response.json()
      setWeatherData(data)
    }
    else{
      setDataLoaded()
    }
    setDataLoaded(true)
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
  console.log(weatherData)

  if(dataLoaded){
    const reverseAddress = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({
      longitude:weatherData.coord.lon,
      latitude:weatherData.coord.lat
    })
    setCity(reverseAddress[0].city)
    console.log(city)
  }
}

useEffect(() =>{
  fetchWeatherDara()
},[])

  if(dataLoaded == false){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Loading....</Text>
       </View>
  )
  }
  
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <WeatherScreen weatherData={weatherData}/>
       </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#1C9CF6',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  cityName:{  
    color:"white",
    fontWeight:'bold',
    fontSize:40
  },
  currentTemp:{
    color:"white",
    fontSize:100,
    fontWeight:200,
    
  },
  highLow:{
    color:"white",
    fontSize:20
  }
});
```

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const WeatherScreen = ({weatherData}) => {
    const {
        name,
        timezone
    } = weatherData;
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{name}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default WeatherScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

When I launch App.js on the first try, I get an error saying "Cannot read propety of 'name' defined (from my WeatherScreen componenet).

When I remove {name} and the object in my WeatherScreen code, the app then refreshes and seems to work fine. I want the app to run on launch without getting the error.

This is the JSON I'm extracting data from, using random lat and lon:
[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qXTN.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you don't have data when the component first loads, it is still being fetched. One thing you can do is check the object before rendering.

```
const WeatherScreen = ({weatherData}) => {

    // no data yet, just return. 
    // This should re-render when the state updates
    if (weatherData === null) {
        return;
    }

    const {
        name,
        timezone
    } = weatherData;
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{name}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const WeatherScreen = ({weatherData}) => {
const {
    name,
    timezone
} = weatherData;
return (
<View>
  <Text>{name!=undefined && name}</Text>
</View>
)
}

export default WeatherScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```